# Cant get my compositing to layer my objects quite right

Tags: rendering, particles, layers

I got this render where i am attempting to get multiple renderlayers to play nice, im trying to get the water and the ships to appear in front of the stars, but for somereason the star-particles wants to be in front of the objects, i have unsuccessfully tried mask-layers and obj-index, but im quite new to this. if anyone has any tips on how to simply ad my 2 new layers to my compositing tree that be tight :)if images are too dark, or if my question isnt understadable ill be happy to explain more :)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your node setup is barely visible. You seem to be adding both layers when in fact it sounds like you should be using an *Alpha Over* instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this issue is the add node just before the final composite node. The node is simply adding the values of the pixels regardless of which is on top. A better way to do it would be to use the Alpha over node, although it's unclear from the images you posted if the render layers with the ships and water have any alpha information. Alternatively, you could set the node to mix instead of add, and then use the object index passes as the factor for the mix node.

Comment: thanks man, ill try that as soon as i get home, do u have any links for a good composition nodes tutorials ? i really cant rap my head around the basics :)